# Both gtag.js tracking snippet and Google tag manager on?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I noticed that both the gtag.js tracking snippet and Google tag manager (with GA tracking tag enabled) were placed at the same time.

Could this cause any tracking issues?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using two Analytics codes in the same site (one directly in the code and another one trough Tag Manager) the consequences are:

- Higher load time (more javascript and external calls to execute)
- If they have the same UA, you will lose real information about bounce rate, time on site or page views (you are executing two hits in every interaction).